# Python: how to plot the normal distribution of a 3-dimensional array

Tags: python, arrays, graph, statistics

I have a 3-dimensional array called `temprSubset` that I have taken the average of across 2 dimensions.

code:

```
f=MFDataset(filenames)

temprSubset = f.variables['tc'][ : , latitude_lower_limit:latitude_upper_limit , longitude_lower_limit:longitude_upper_limit,] 

tempavg1=temprSubset.mean(axis=tuple(range(0,2)))
```

I want to plot the standard deviation curve for each average in tempavg1 array but I am lost.

Comment: Care to share the data and the attempted solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy way is to use the [`hist`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html) function. The choice of the number of bins could significantly change the shape of the graph.

Another method, which gives a smooth curve, is the [kernel density estimation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gaussian_kde.html). The choice of the bandwidth could also change the shape of the obtained graph.

```
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

# Generate some data
data = np.random.normal( size=(5, 50, 150) )  # a random 3D array
average_axes01 = data.mean(axis=(0, 1))

# Using the Kernel density estimation:
from scipy.stats import gaussian_kde

prob_density = gaussian_kde(average_axes01)
std = average_axes01.std()
x_fine = np.linspace(-3*std, 3*std, 29)
probs = prob_density(x_fine)
plt.plot(x_fine, probs, 'r', linewidth=2);

# Using the histogram:
plt.hist(average_axes01, bins=7, normed=True, alpha=.4)

plt.ylabel('probability density function'); plt.xlabel('values');
```

[image: example graph]